Name of this cartoon series with a witch as the main antagonist
I'm forgetting the name of this cartoon that used to air when I was a kid, whose antagonist was a very old witch who used to ride on a broom, with her owl. At the end of the cartoon, the credits would roll whilst the background has the with witch riding the broom, and it all looked like an arcade style video game. She would also sing this catchy tune called which I think was supposedly called "being a witch is fun". 
I got reminded of it when I came across this character on the web that looks like her.

I also remember there were either 3 kids or 3 pigs, something like that.
Does anybody know the title/name of the cartoon series. Does it still air or can it be found anywhere on the interwebs.

Hi. Do you remember the approximate year\decade? The country\language?

And it's not that one? Because it has 3 triplets that can be seen there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LG6kLDl5ZbM (Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Triplets, from the original Catalan name and your native language, you should be able to find it in your idiom)

So, this is a picture from the actual show?... Er, didn't it say on the page where it was from?

It aired in English

It's Les Tres bessones (Las tres mellizas) (1995–2003). It's a spanish animated television series. It is based on the short stories by Roser Capdevila.

IMDB:

Anna, Teresa and Helena are naughty triplets that always get into a
  mess. As punishment the Bored Witch sends the girls into a tale in
  order to learn the lesson.

Wikipedia /
Filmaffinity



Intro (Youtube) 

I think it looks like the one. Was it aired in English too???

Yes, it was. The series has been translated into the following languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Triplets
